# How to set up a rewrite rule for an ASP site?

Tags: url-rewriting, web-config, rules

I would like to redirect any `photo.asp?id=` here is anything after the =
to `photographe.asp?id=` here is anything after the =

example

`photo.asp?id=161#photographie-automobile`

to

`photographe.asp?id=161#photographie-automobile`

or

`photo.asp?id=230#road-suv`

to

`photographe.asp?id=230#road-suv`

Code below:

```
<rule name="SpecificRedirect" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^photo.asp$" />
            <action type="Redirect" url="/photographe.asp$" 
redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
```

Comment: find it....if you search... here the code   <rule name="Specificphoto-reportagecorpoRedirect" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^photo.asp(.*)$" />
        <action type="Redirect" url="/photographe.asp{R:1}"  redirectType="Permanent" />
      </rule>

Comment: Is this for IIS? If so, please tag the question with that technology. If your comment is the answer, please add a self-answer below, using the "Answer your own question" button. Thanks!